# Cypress mouseenter event

Tags: cypress

```
`    <div class="level-0 flex-1 transition duration-500 group hover:bg-primary-darker"      @mouseenter="hoverPanelActiveId = '41'" @mouseleave="hoverPanelActiveId = 0"> `
```

When using cypress to target the above element in the nav menu i am unable to trigger the mouseenter event. On hover a panel appears with a list of links under the nav bar. While viewing in browser it will trigger but when i run a automated test nothing seems to happen

i have tried:

```
`     .trigger('mouseenter') .trigger('mouseover') .invoke('show'`)
```

None of the above solutions triggered the additional panel which contains the sub nav menu

[desired nav bar interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgygG.png)

could anyone give me some solutions to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress natively doesn't have a hover command. But there are some workarounds.

Your attempts might not have worked because using `.trigger()` will only affect events in JavaScript and will not trigger any effects in CSS.

---

If you add a `.click({ force: true })` behind `.invoke('show')` it might work. Since it skips all checks, it will always fire the event at the desired element.

---

You could try it with  [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events)

Register new commands by adding this to your cypress/support/index.{js,ts} file.

```
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

And in your code, you can directly write:

```
cy.contains("a", "Custom").realHover('mouse')
```